# How to count overall post activity(likes, dislikes, comment) from postModel and reference sum of those in userModel using mongodb and mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema, mern

I use MERN Stack to create social network, I need to implement count for overall user's posts activity(likes, comment, dislikes) and be able to access that sum in Profile, when fetching that through REST API.

The goal is to implement scoring system, where the next calculation will define the score (Likes+comment-dislikes = score).

Code for Post Model:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema({

    user: { //we want post to be connected to the user
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: { //name of user to keep posts even if the user delets the account
        type: String
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String
    },
    likes: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        }
    }],
    dislikes: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        }
    }],

    comments: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        name: { //name of user to keep comments even if the user delets the account
            type: String
        },
        avatar: {
            type: String
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],

    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);
```

Code for profile

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //every profile is associated with user, so connect with user.id
        ref: 'user' //reference to user model
    },
    website: {
        type: String
    },
    location: {
        type: String
    },
    bio: {
        type: String
    },
    activity_count: {
        type: Number,
        ref: 'post'
    },

    social: {
        youtube: {
            type: String
        },
        twitter: {
            type: String
        },
        facebook: {
            type: String
        },
        linkedin: {
            type: String
        },
        instagram: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema)
```

Comment: Please share input and output you want at https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 0):

If this was a sql database it would make sense to implement some queries that calculates each user's score in database side.

But with mongodb you have to take a different approach. In general, doing any sort of calculations in the database side is very inefficient. Mongodb server converts all the relevant the BSON documents into javascript object and then does calculates with javascript which is relatively slow.

Instead of calculating the score for every request, you should store the score and probably also the counts of likes, comment and dislikes in the post document.

Also remember that in MongoDB(NoSQL), denormalizing is not a bad thing.
If you need to do some calculation for every database request, its a sing to store the calculated data in a new field.

For example when someone adds a comment you probably do something like this:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:postId }, { $push: { comments: newComment })
```

Now just change this to

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:postId }, { $push: { comments: newComment }, { $inc: { commentCount: 1, score: 1 } } )
```

When some deletes a post

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({ _id:postId }, { $pull: { 'comments.id': commentId }, { $inc: { commentCount: -1, score: -1 } } )
```

Now all these requests are very fast because these updates are handled in BSON. You can apply this same logic to your profile document.